# Does TypeScript support export default Enum?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, export

I have an enum object which I want to make the export default at the top level like that :

```
export default enum Hashes{

FOO = 'foo',
BAR = 'bar',
}
```

I got this error :

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:15) File was processed with
> these loaders: [02:54] MABROUK, Sahnoun (external - Project)
>
> - ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
> - ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js

I tried this way :

```
export enum Hashes{
    
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar',
    }
```

and it seems work only if I import Hashes as alias in all my components like that :

import {Hashes} from ... which is a huge change in my project !

any solution ?

Comment: `export default ...` only works with *expressions* and it looks like `enum X { ... }` is not an expression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how ES6 works.

```
enum Hashes {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}

export default Hashes;
```

Exporting it as const? Concerning the default export, there is only a single default export per module. A default export can be a function, a class, an object or anything else. This value is to be considered as the "main" exported value since it will be the simplest to import.

```
export const enum Hashes {
  FOO = 'foo',
  BAR = 'bar',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`export default expects an expression/function/class after it`, you can read here more [Export MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

This is not due to TS, this is due to an error in your statement. You can simply define your enum first and then `export default` it.

```
enum Hashes {
 FOO = 'foo',
 BAR = 'bar',
}

export default Hashes
```